# angularjs not updating model value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

In my example I want to update model when user focus the textfield. In short append 'px' string to the existing value.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="PixelCtrl">
  <div>
  {{pixel}}
  </div>
    <input type="text" ng-focus="updatePX($event)" ng-model="pixel" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function PixelCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pixel = "120";

  $scope.updatePX = function(e){
  debugger;
   alert(e.target.value);
    e.target.value = e.target.value + "px";
    $scope.$apply();
  }
}
```

As you all can see I have also used `$scope.$apply`. Most likely I am doing something wrong.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/U3pVM/27621/

Comment: Have you considered just adding the `px` to the binding? For example, `{{pixel}}px`

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing, do you need "px" literally on the model or just to display it?

Comment: I need 'px' appended to the model so that when I use model value in another scenario then I should get 'px' as well. Also another reason I want to do this way is because there is an extra overhead to the user to always write px after numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manually add the 'px' text. Simply add it by default

```js
function PixelCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pixel = "120";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="PixelCtrl">
    <div ng-show="pixel">
      {{pixel}} px
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="pixel" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include 1.2.1 angular version. Here is your solution:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/U3pVM/27631/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="PixelCtrl">
   <div>
      {{pixel}}
   </div>
   <input type="text" ng-focus="updatePX($event)" ng-model="pixel" />
  </div>
</div>



function PixelCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.pixel = "120";
   $scope.updatePX = function(e){
     e.target.value = e.target.value + "px";
     $scope.pixel=e.target.value;
   }
}
```

Comment: I checked you fiddle and on focus event
(1) I am getting error
(2) Model is not updated as updaed value is not shown in div(view)

Comment: Now,it works perfectly for me.Please try my jsfiddle !.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexandru Mihai said, upgrade angular version.

See example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/U3pVM/27634/).

```js
angular.module("testApp", [])
  .controller("PixelCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.pixel = "120";

    $scope.updatePX = function(e) {
      if ($scope.pixel && $scope.pixel.indexOf("px") === -1)
        $scope.pixel += "px";
    }
  })
  .directive("myPixel", function() {
    return {
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
        element.on("focus", function() {
          var val = ngModel.$viewValue;
          if (val && val.indexOf("px") === -1) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue + "px");
            element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
  .directive("myPixelBetter", function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        value: "=myPixelBetter"
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.on("focus", function() {
          if (scope.value && scope.value.indexOf("px") === -1) {
            scope.value += "px";
            scope.$apply();
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="PixelCtrl">
    <div>
      {{pixel}}
    </div>
    <div>

      With ng-focus
      <input type="text" ng-focus="updatePX()" ng-model="pixel" />
    </div>
    <div>
      With custom directive
      <input type="text" my-pixel ng-model="pixel" />
    </div>
    <div>
      With custom directive. Better solution
      <input type="text" my-pixel-better="pixel" ng-model="pixel" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```